# OpenNMS REST Api: Retrieving performance stats using /measurements

Tags: opennms

I am fairly new to OpenNMS. Currently I am in the process of creating a simplified dashboard for all the nodes that I have configured. I plan on monitoring the cpu utilization and the memory availability on all the nodes. To do this, I am using the REST Api of OpenNMS. For the cpu utilization, I am able to get the stats using the following url :

```
http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/measurements/node%5B212%5D.nodeSnmp%5B%5D/cpuPercentBusy?start=1501158186498&maxrows=30
```

From https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/ReST#Measurements_API, I was able to get the basic url as :

```
/measurements/{resourceId}/{attribute}
```

However, I can't seem to determine the url for getting the memory available on the various disk drives (C:\,D:\,etc...)

How do I get the memory utilization and other performance metrics for a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the official wiki page for OpennNMS, managed to find the appropriate REST query.
In my case for C:\ drive, it was :

```
http://localhost:8980/opennms/rest/measurements/node%5B212%5D.hrStorageIndex[C]/hrStorageSize?start=1501158186498
```

I managed to get other stats in a similar manner.

Links to documentation I refered :

> https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/Data_Collection_Configuration_How-To
>   https://wiki.opennms.org/wiki/ReST#Measurements_API